# How can I get matlab's mexcuda command to locate gcc version 8 in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: matlab, cuda, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to use MATLAB's CUDA to compile some on-GPU code. When I run the command

```
mexcuda -largeArrayDims mexThSpkPC.cu
```

I get the following error:

```
>> mexcuda -largeArrayDims mexThSpkPC.cu
Building with 'nvcc'.
Error using mex
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than
8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~


Error in mexcuda (line 166)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = mex(mexArguments{:});
```

What's strange is that I've installed `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` from apt, and it pulls in `gcc` version 8 as well as `g++`. So they're there on my system. How do I get MATLAB (or the nvida CUDA compiler) to find the right version of `gcc`/`g++`? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some digging, I discovered that the MATLAB code looks for the `CUDA_PATH` environment variable. So starting matlab as:

```
CUDA_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit  matlab
```

solves the problem for me!